# Should questions about 'customized' Blender 'mods' be considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are some customized Blender distributions.

- https://blendersensei.com
- http://www.microvellum.com/products/fluid-designer

And a question about one of them here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31917/blender-sensei-format-select-deselect

Should these be considered off topic?

Comment: I'd say it depends on if there are users here who can/will answer. Not sure if there are or not

Comment: Anyone can make a branch of Blender and make arbitrary changes, I think there is some limit to what **blender.stackexchange** should handle. However we could treat this the same way as we do very old blender versions. *"It's not off topic, but YMMV getting help."*

Comment: I guess maybe the best strategy for the time being is wait to see what happens (do such questions get answers, and are more such questions asked), then decided based on that.

Comment: When I just saw the title in the side bar, I though [mods](http://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking that questions about mods like fluid designer should be highly discouraged. If you look at the interface of fluid designer, it's a ton different than stock Blender. Most of the things that someone would conventionally use Fluid Designer for, don't really use much of Blenders original UI.

Something more like the Sensei format should be allowed with the understanding that a question might not get answered if it has something to do with the added features.

The reason why I make a distinction between Fluid Designer and Sensei format here, is because Fluid designer has much more changes to the internal code, while sensei format is basically just an addon with a custom theme.

Also, what do people think about the support for the Fracture Modifier? My personal standing on this is that it should be supported. Mainly because the developers are still aiming to get it into master, weather that happens or not, and because I'm biased and I like the tool.

It's still a lot like Fluid Designer in the fact that it's a major addon. You can use all the normal features of Blender in those builds, but when you come to the real reason of using it, it's quite different than Blender.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should (at this point) be open to questions about these modified versions of blender.

There is nothing to be gained as of now to setting a hard and fast rule banning all questions that are not about the "stock" version of blender. We just do not have enough time or data about those questions on this site.
Like gandalf said, if it turns out that the community here does not answer them, or there is not enough activity to warrant them being on this site; then we can come back and make those type of questions off topic.

Comment: yeah people will get the message if zero/few microvellum questions get answered by us, i'd expect them to have a reasonable support mechanism anyway since it is a paid product.